# How to align notification content text in android

Tags: android

I'm developing android notifications.

My notification has a progressbar and I want to show the percentage below the progressbar, notificationBuilder.setContentText(MyPercentage) area.

Showing progress percentage is not difficult issue.

but **I want to show my percentage text
with right alignment.**

[This is an example picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amwkK.jpg)

My situation is more complicated than that example,

Because I have to show another information with progress

like

```
============================================-------------------------------------------

blablablabla, orange, apple                                                      50%
```

Is there any simple way to align my notification contentText right?

If not, then how can I implement  notification  contentText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom layout for your notification with two TextViews, where one is aligned to the right. Then create a RemoteViews object (notificationView) for that layout and set the builder's content accordingly: `notificationBuilder.setContent(notificationView);`

Here is a tutorial on creating custom notification layouts: http://www.laurivan.com/android-notifications-with-custom-layout/

**Example**

The notification layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/the_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/some_text_left"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/some_text_right"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Creating notificationView:

```
private RemoteViews getNotificationView(){
    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_temperature_notificaiton);

    notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon, R.drawable.le_icon);
    notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.the_title, "OMGWTFBBQ");
    notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.some_text_left, "blablablabla, orange, apple");
    notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.some_text_right, "50%");

    return notificationView;
}
```

Showing the notification:

```
private void addNotification() {
    RemoteViews notificationView = getNotificationView();

    if(notificationView == null)
        return;

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.le_icon);

    notificationBuilder.setContent(notificationView);

    ....

    manager.notify(NOTIFICAITON_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```